# React Native unable to build, after generating Optimisation Profile

Tags: xcode, react-native

My app was working fine on IOS and I really have no idea of Native iOS development. I saw an option to Generate Optimization Profile although after facing the error I understand that I really don't need this.

So after selecting this option Xcode asked to enable profile optimization I said yes and then after building the app Xcode gave an error that profiling can't be done. From then whenever I try to build the app I am getting.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/sushant/Documents/Web/gw-ios/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGEnums.o /Users/sushant/Documents/Web/gw-ios/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

on simulator as well as on device.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If u use a version control system like GIT,  check the diff and checkout the file which you think might be causing the trouble.

Comment: You didn't specify any versions. Please try with Xcode 9.1, React Native 48.3, iOS 11.1...I checked that my project built prior to enabling Profile Guided Optimisation. Then I enabled it using the Run option (rather than test) and everything built and ran fine. The only files changed were the xcode project and a generated data file. So if I were you I'd do a sanity check and make sure everything builds ok before PGO is activated.

Comment: There was some file of node_modules that was updated by Xcode, Reinstalling the node_modules fixed the issue.